# Haskell error: Variable not in scope: myEven

Tags: haskell

Why is my variable not in scope? 
It seems everything is ok, but it does not work

```
myEven::[Int] -> [Int]
myEven [] = []
myEven (x:xs) = if x `mod` 2 == 0 then x:myEven xs 
                else myEven xs
```

I am testing now and it's working but without first line. 
Where is my mistake?

Another question, how to rewrite this function in Pattern matching

Comment: Your function looks fine to me, so I don’t have any idea what could be going wrong. Could you possibly post the full error message, along with the command you ran that produced it?

Comment: I'm sorry surprisingly it works now. Do you know an answer on my second question?

Comment: This smells rather strongly like homework, so I’m reluctant to just give you an answer, but I can tell you that you probably want to use *guards*.

Comment: "how to rewrite this function in Pattern matching" You're already using pattern matching. The only change I'd make is using guards instead of an `if/then/else`.

Comment: Ok thanks, It is not a Homework but it is my own exercise.

Comment: Did you accidentally use `myeven` or something similar, instead of `myEven`, at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my variable not in scope?

Perhaps you failed to load the file or perhaps something else, hard to say without seeing the error and your invocation.  Either way, glad it's working.

> Another question, how to rewrite this function in Pattern matching

You are already using pattern matching on the list.  Do you want to pattern match on the `Int`? You can't, for example, match on bits but I can see how that would be neat `(highBits # 0b0) : xs = x : myEven xs`.

Instead you can use guards:

```
myEven ::[Int] -> [Int]
myEven [] = []
myEven (x:xs) | x `mod` 2 == 0 = x : myEven xs
              | otherwise      = myEven xs
```

Answer (score 1):

> Another question, how to rewrite this function in Pattern matching

You're already pattern matching on what's available for pattern matching. In any case, just for fun (I don't recommend this) you can turn those guards into patterns using ghc extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

pattern Even n <- (\x -> x <$ guard (x `mod` 2 == 0) -> Just n) where Even n = n
pattern Odd  n <- (\x -> x <$ guard (x `mod` 2 == 1) -> Just n) where Odd  n = n 

myEven ::[Int] -> [Int]
myEven [] = []
myEven (Even x :xs) = x : myEven xs
myEven (Odd  x :xs) = myEven xs
```